# How to generalize a class based on operator() arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a class that is supposed to forward some arguments to a functor, but doing some additional stuff.

```
class SemaphoredEventRouterObserver {
   My_Semaphore m_semaphore;
   mywrapper_Function<void (*)(const Event &)> callback;
   SemaphoredEventRouterObserver(My_Semaphore semaphore, mywrapper_Function<void (*)(const Event &)> o_callback) : m_semaphore(semaphore) {
      callback = o_callback;
   }
   void operator()(const Event & event) {
      callback(event);
      semaphone.post();
   }
}
```

The problem is I might have to create dozens of classes like this, because for other functors the arguments vary, so instead of receiving `const Event & event`, I could receive `string arg`, `int c`, `Myclass abc` or anything else.

Is it possible to create a template class for this? I am using just stl and I cannot use boost, although I would be curious to see answers related to boost as well.

Comment: What about forwarding variadic template parameters? See here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With variadic template, you may do something like:

```
typename <typename... Ts>
class SemaphoredRouterObserver {
   My_Semaphore m_semaphore;
   mywrapper_Function<void (*)(Ts...)> callback;
public:
   SemaphoredEventRouterObserver(My_Semaphore semaphore,
                                 mywrapper_Function<void (*)(Ts...)> o_callback)
     : m_semaphore(semaphore),
       callback(o_callback)
   {}
   void operator()(Ts... args) {
      callback(args...);
      semaphone.post();
   }
};
```

And then

```
using SemaphoredEventRouterObserver = SemaphoredRouterObserver<const Event&>;
```